# Php Pear Remote-Install "Error: remote-install expects either option "remoteconfig" be set, or remote_config configuration variable be used"

Tags: php, pear

I am setting up PHP and Pear Remote install on my local server.

As per the instructions here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

I have 'setup' the remote configuration using this, obviously replacing the details with my FTP details.

```
$ pear -c remote.conf config-set remote_config \
    ftp://user:pass@myremotehost.com/.pearrc
```

remote.conf

> a:13:{s:7:"php_dir";s:25:"/home/bentstuart/pear/php";s:8:"data_dir";s:26:"/home/bentstuart/pear/data";s:7:"www_dir";s:25:"/home/bentstuart/pear/www";s:7:"cfg_dir";s:25:"/home/bentstuart/pear/cfg";s:7:"ext_dir";s:25:"/home/bentstuart/pear/ext";s:7:"doc_dir";s:26:"/home/bentstuart/pear/docs";s:8:"test_dir";s:27:"/home/bentstuart/pear/tests";s:9:"cache_dir";s:27:"/home/bentstuart/pear/cache";s:12:"download_dir";s:30:"/home/bentstuart/pear/download";s:8:"temp_dir";s:26:"/home/bentstuart/pear/temp";s:7:"bin_dir";s:21:"/home/bentstuart/pear";s:10:"__channels";a:3:{s:12:"pecl.php.net";a:0:{}s:5:"__uri";a:0:{}s:11:"doc.php.net";a:0:{}}s:13:"remote_config";s:92:"IGZ0cDovL3VzZXI6MTgwNDc2MF9hZG1pbkB3aWtpcHJvamVjdC5teXByZXNzb25saW5lLmNvbS9wZWFyLy5wZWFycmM=";}

Then via the terminal `pear remote-install`

I get:

> Error: remote-install expects either option "remoteconfig" be
>   set, or remote_config configuration variable be used

As you can see the remote.conf has been configured, perhaps the remote.conf needs to be in a specific folder that pear looks for it? the documentation on remote-install is very slim.

I would be delighted to hear from anyone whom has successfully installed pears remote-install package.

I am doing it this way obviously because I don't have SSH access and need pear packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the remote configuration to your install command:

```
$ pear -c remote.conf remote-install ....
```